# How to calculate a density matrix of a given circuit?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, quantum-circuit

I want to find the density matrix of the following quantum circuit, is it correct: [image]

[[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]
[0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j
0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j 0.12499999+0.j]]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What did you do so far or how would you propose to proceed? Moreover, please use MathJax to type the matrix. As currently showed, it is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DensityMatrix.from_instruction` in Qiskit to find the density matrix corresponding to a quantum circuit. Here is the relevant code:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
from numpy import sqrt

q0_initial = [sqrt(3)/2, 1/2]

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.initialize(q0_initial, 0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(0, 2)
qc.h([0, 1, 2])
display(qc.draw())

density_matrix = DensityMatrix.from_instruction(qc)
print(density_matrix.data)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

```
[[0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j
  0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j]
 [0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j
  0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j]
 [0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j
  0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j]
 [0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j
  0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j]
 [0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j
  0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j]
 [0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j
  0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j]
 [0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j
  0.0625    +0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.23325318+0.j 0.0625    +0.j]
 [0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j
  0.01674682+0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.0625    +0.j 0.01674682+0.j]]
```

This density matrix is different from the one you posted in the question. The density matrix you posted in the question looks like the result of applying only the three $H$ gates, and not the first part of the circuit.